# ASP setting control value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controls

From a list of names i dynamically create anchor tags on an aspx  form page. The result of each is as follows with different names/IDs/titles.

```html
From a list of names i dynamically create achor tags on an aspx  form page.
<a target= href="mailto:johnbrown@site.net" onclick="updateSql(document.getElementById('PersonJB'))" runat="server" id="PersonJB" title="JB">John Brown</a>
```

Java function updateSql is

```js
      function update(passLink) {
            /* alert("this dialogue has been invoked through codebehind.");  */
            document.getElementById('<%= btnUpdateSql.ClientID%>').click();
                 }
```

btnUpdateSql is defined hidden

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdateSqlt" runat="server"  Text="Button" CssClass="hidden"/>
```

It all seems to work. except I want the click event to be aware of the different link that was  clicked.
What I want to achieve: Update btnUpdateSql text with the ID or title of the passed link before called the click event in the javascript function.
How can I set the button text in the Java function? Or how can i use another hidden field?
The purpose being to update SQL table in the click event using the initials as a key.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, multiple links triggering a button click event under the hood is very fragile.

Why not use **[LinkButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx)** since you are posting back to server anyway.

The advanatage is LinkButton has **CommandArgument** and **CommandName**. All links can use same [Common Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.command(v=vs.110).aspx), and you can see which link trigger the event by looking at the **CommandArgument**.

*If you do not plan to postback to server, you will need to redesign the application to use **Ajax**. It is out of the scope of original question.*